# How to get Tags, Title, Subject Manager etc from powerpoint (or other) files in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to this, so please treat me as a Noob :-)

I'm using .net and trying to write a small project for my wifes non-for-profit..

She needs to update the 'tags' section of powerpoint files (File -> Info -> Tags, or SaveAs, Tags)

My intention is to 'search' through all ppt documents in a folder. Count how many time 'keywords' are there, then update the 'Tags' section with the keyword and count (if that makes sense).

Eg.

PPT file may have the keywords:

ABC
DEF
GHI

I'll search for each of the above, the count them up. I'll then want to update the 'keywords' section with:

ABC=5, DEF=0, GHI=9

{or something like that}

Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I'm on the wrong track here.

What I'm actually wanting to do is count the number of specific 'words' in the PPT (or pptx) file and then update the 'tags' section.

Looks like I can't search for 'specific words' in PPT files in .net and I'm going to have to use VBA and macros to do this... (unless anybody can point me in the right/other direction :-)  )

Comment: Please update this information into your question. This "answer" section is for people (or you) posting answers.